# Loop for matrix does not jump R

Tags: r, matrix

I guess this is a very easy question, however I don't understand why my loop does not jump:

I have a prefilled matrix:

```
  0     1     2   3 ...  22
1 1/22 1/22 1/22 1/22 .. 1/22
2 1/22 1/22 1/22 1/22.. 
3 1/22
..
22 1/22..            ..  1/22
```

and now I want to have a matrix where the column name stands for the first number of rows where there is still a 1/22 in it and replace the rest with 1/25:

```
0     1     2   3 ...  22
1 1/22 1/22 1/22 1/22 .. 1/22
2 1/22 1/25 1/22 1/22.. 
3 1/22 1/25 1/25 1/22
..1/22 1/25 1/25 1/25
22 1/22..            ..  1/22
```

I wrote this code which should run onwards from column two, however it only fills out the first row?

```
for(i in 2:nrow(Matrix22)){
for(j in 2:ncol(Matrix22)){
Matrix22[i:22,j] <- 1/25
}
}
```

Comment: Why not simply:  `Matrix22[lower.tri(Matrix22,TRUE)]  <- 1/25; Matrix22[,1] <- 1/22` Fill the lower triangle and just reset the first column after.

Comment: Thank you very much @Tensibai :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution by Tensibai is definitely better in this example, but to fix your original for loop solution you can also do the following

```
Matrix22<-matrix(rep(1/22,484),nrow=22,ncol=22)

for(j in 2:ncol(Matrix22)){
      Matrix22[j:nrow(Matrix22),j] <- 1/25
}
```

As you can see the nested for loops were not necessary as the column number determines the starting row where numbers need to be changed.

Comment: Thank you @Niek :)